# "Mockito cannot mock this class" error even if I am using powermockito to mock the class

Tags: java, junit4, powermockito, final-class

I have a final class

```
public final class A {
    private static final Set<String> B = methodA();

    private static Set<String> methodA() {
        //does some processing and 
        //returns a set 
    }

    public static boolean methodB() {
        //does some processing and 
        //returns a boolean 
    }
}
```

The class under test is class B.
This class is calling the static method of the final class A

```
public class B {
    public boolean methodC() {
       if(methodB()) {
         C.methodD();
       }
    }
}
```

The class C is again a final class

```
public final class C {

    public static void methodD() {
        //does some processing
    }
}
```

I am mocking this final class A like this

```
public class TestB {

    public void testMethodC() {
        PowerMockito.mock(A.class); 
    }
}
```

The case is failing inside the methodD of class C. 
I am getting this error **Mockito cannot mock this class: A.**

Answer (score 0):

You need some annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class})
public class TestB {

    public void testMethodC() {
        PowerMockito.mock(A.class); 
    }
}
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried and for me works: I didn't get your exception. Is the exception changed? If yes, can you add more details?

Comment: Added my dependecies, check them. My code works fine.

Comment: have same dependencies:)

Comment: The only idea I heve is that the code you posted is not comparable to what you actually have

Comment: the issue got solved, thanks. I specified a wrong path in system.properties, thats why it was failing